# Add second key combination to switch between keyboard layouts in Xubuntu

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, language

In windows you can switch between English and Bulgarian language with Alt + Shift. But there is an option to switch between Bulgarian Traditional and Bulgarian Phonetic layout using Ctrl + Shift. When you press again Alt + Shift you switch to English layout again.

So with Alt + Shift you switch between languages and with Ctrl + Shift you swith between same language kayboard variants.

Is there a way to achieve that in linux. I am currently using Xubuntu 14.04.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question - the "Ibus Preferences", which are located in Settings -> Keyboard Input Methods in Xubuntu.

There in the General tab you can specify the keys combination to switch between combination of keyboards. In the second tab - Input Method, you can customize which keyboard layouts to switch.

I recommend to turn on the checkbox "Show icon on system try" in the General tab.